# What does Range("Q1048576") mean

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I have to work with a previous colleague's work. I have a code to auto-refresh an excel file, and I am trying to understand this range ("Q1048576") as I have several such in other scripts.. Thanks for your assistance

**code**

```
Sub RefreshSalesData()

Dim Location9 As String
Dim Archive9 As String
Dim Location9Archive9 As String

Sheets("Data").Select
Range("Q1048576").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Now()


Location9 = "C:\Users\fred\Documents\data_to_refresh"
Archive9 = "SalesData.xlsx"
  
Location9Archive9 = Location9 & Archive9
```

Answer (score 1):

1048576 is a hard-coded last row number in Q column. It is rather bad practice, because it is not compatible with older .xls format (.xlsx has exactly 1048576 rows, .xls about 65k) and would cause run-time error, because 1048576 row doesn't exists in .xls files. But even worse is using select for no purpose [How to avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Change this fragment:

```
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("Q1048576").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Now()
```

To:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
   .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Now()
End With
```

Also remeber to fully qualify your ranges. For example:

```
Sheets("Data")
```

is implicite the same as:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
```

which can be dangerous probably if you have few workbooks open. If you want to make changes in current workbook (which contains the macro code), you can use:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
```